# IOS 5 Core Data, how to have NSFetchedResultsController return results matching the parent one to many relationship?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I'm trying to find the easiest way to present a limited set of managed objects with Core Data.

I have a **one user to many events** relationship defined in Core Data.

I need to be able to have my UITableViewControllers display results for one user at a time, while retaining the ability to insert/delete events for that user. If I just needed to display the data, I would've taken the NSSet and converted it to be a tableview data source. **I would like to preserve the ability to add/delete and edit events, but only for the currently active user.**

I was thinking of setting my NSFetchedResultsController to nil every time I need to change the user, and then re-initialize it like below. This preserves the ability to work with data, but requires some property to filter data with.

Currently I'm thinking of implementing this like this: **have an ID property defined for the user, then add the same ID to all events for the user.** This will allow me to use `NSPredicate` to search for the user's events, like defined below.

**Is there an alternative way to solve my problem using Core Data relationships? I feel there must be, but I can't see it.**

Here's the code that I use for searching: I swap between presenting this `NSFetchedResultsController` for partial results and a regular `NSFetchedResultsController` for full results.

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)searchFetchedResultsController
{
    if (__searchFetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return __searchFetchedResultsController;
    }

    // Set up the fetched results controller.
    // Create the fetch request for the entity.
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    //    NSString *attributeName = @"type";
    //    //    NSString *attributeValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",dateID];
    //    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %i",
    //                              attributeName, 0];
    //    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
    //    
    //    NSString *attributeName = @"type";
    //    //    NSString *attributeValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",dateID];

    NSPredicate *notesPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"notes CONTAINS[cd]%@", self.searchString];

    NSPredicate *namePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[cd]%@", self.searchString];

    NSPredicate* compoundPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:notesPredicate,namePredicate, nil]];

        [fetchRequest setPredicate:compoundPredicate];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
#warning cache may prevent search results from updating
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"dayID" cacheName:@"SearchResults"];
    self.searchFetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.searchFetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        /*
         Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

         abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
         */
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
//      abort();
    }
    NSLog(@"found objects: %i",[__searchFetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects count]);

    return __searchFetchedResultsController;
}
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach of setting the `NSFetchedResultsController` to `nil` is robust. The fetched results controller should be created lazily and you just set it to `nil` if you need to change the predicate.

There is indeed no need for your own id field. In your fetch request for the events, just make a predicate like so:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
   @"user = %@", userObject];
```

where "user" would be the name you have given to the relationship in the event entity.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to make a ID field in the Event entity to identify the User. You said you already have a relationship setup user->event. Relationships go both ways (assuming you set it up that way, it is called bidirectional and it is best practice to always use them) so you can easily create a NSPredicate that looks for events where user = user.